# How to utilize "Public types, methods and fields (API) should be documented" rule in sonarqube to measure the level of javadoc coverage

Tags: sonarqube, javadoc

Since the release of [Sonarqube 6.1](https://www.sonarsource.com/resources/product-news/news.html#2016-10-12-sonarqube-6.1-released) the "Public Documented API (%)" metric is no longer available. It has been removed with the argumentation that before the mentioned adaptation there were offered two ways to track undocumented API (javadoc in my case):

1. By using the "Public types, methods and fields (API) should be documented" rule.
2. By using the "Public Documented API (%)" measure.

The second one has been removed ([JIRA](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-554)). The problem is that they have removed a metric and left a rule.
We had been using the specified metric as one of the KPIs measuring our code quality, although in general it is criticized as a bad practice ([JIRA](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-554)), in the time being we need to come up with calculating a new quality KPI addressing the specific aspect (1).

(1) Currently I am not sure how to utilize "Public types, methods and fields (API) should be documented" rule in order to measure the level of remaining undocumented API. The most viable suggestion is to measure the total number of documented public public types methods and fields and calculate the percentage but again, I am not sure which rule to use to calculate this.

(2) A prerequisite would also be to have it available in the Timemachine dashboard but this is secondary.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

---

[image]